# NumPy linspace rounding error

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

Could someone explain this rounding issue with `numpy.linspace`?

```
import numpy as np

np.linspace(0, 1, 6) == np.around( np.linspace(0, 1, 6), 10 )
# array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Here's how I arrived here...

```
import numpy as np

## Two ways of defining the same thing
A = np.array([ 0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ])
B = np.linspace(0, 1, 6)

## A and B appear to be the same
A # array([ 0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ])
B # array([ 0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ])


## They're not
A == B # array([ True, True, True, False, True, True], dtype=bool)
A - B  # array([ 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, -1.11022302e-16, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00])


## Gotta round to get my expected result
C = np.round( np.linspace( 0, 1, 6 ), 10 )
C      # array([ 0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ])
A == C # array([ True, True, True, True, True, True], dtype=bool)
```

The way I defined `B` seems innocent enough . . . is this rounding issue something that can bite us all over the place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not pretty, but its the way floating point is, you are going to have to learn to live with it. This is where your weird result comes from:

```
>>> a = np.float(1)
>>> a /= 5
>>> a
0.2
>>> a*3
0.6000000000000001
```

You have [`np.allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) to help you deal with this kind of stuff, but if you are not disciplined about floating point comparisons then yes, it will bite you over and over again.